# How to run sudo su from php script without password?

Tags: php, linux, scripting, sudo, sudoers

I am making a PHP script in which I have to send mail with attachment. I am using mutt and the command is...

```
echo 'This is the body' | mutt -s 'Testing mutt' 1nonlyabhishek002@gmail.com -a /home/jyoti/ab.txt
```

...but the problem I am facing is that it works only with `sudo su` so I want to use `sudo su` in my PHP script without password. Please suggest me the way I can run `sudo su` in my PHP script.

I will be happy if there is way to run using password in script, that would be fine too. All I want is to execute the above command with `sudo su` with password or without password. Security doesn't matter.

Comment: Most people think that security does matter.

Comment: i know but as i have to complete this as earliest as i can this is my final year project part.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the web server user to run your script with no password, add to your sudoers file, in this example `apache` is the web server user:

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/php/file.php
```

You can use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i am using xampp so will this be same oe i need to put www-data there ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Possibly www-data, do a list of users and see which it is.

Comment: it didnt woked fro me i want to use echo 'This is the body' | mutt -s 'Testing mutt' 1nonlyabhishek002@gmail.com -a /home/jyoti/ab.txt commans